# Python multiprocessing example does nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm trying to learn python multiprocessing, but when I try to run the following example code from the documentation, nothing happens. Nothing is printed, no exceptions, nothing.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

However, the other example works just as intended:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

I've checked to see if it's an enviroment-specific problem and now I'm even more confused. If I run the first example I showed in IDLE, it doesn't work. If I run it in the interactive interpreter in the command prompt, it also doesn't work. But if I run a .py file with the same code with the command prompt, it works. Does anybody know what's actually happening and why running the same code yields different results?

(I'm currently on a Windows 10 machine if that's important)

Comment: it's working...

Answer (score 3):

IDLE has exceptionally weird behaviors due to replacing `sys.stdout` and company; interactive or not, you can end up with some strange behaviors.

`multiprocessing` in general doesn't work very well in the interactive interpreter, particularly on Windows where the "fork simulation" can't really simulate it properly.

Stick to testing `multiprocessing` related stuff in actual scripts.